# Can't find RestComm SMPP Server link

Tags: restcomm

I recently just installed RestComm SMSC gateway. On the left hand side in the management section, I'm missing the SMPP server link. Did I miss something during install? Also missing the ESMEs link.

Also can we use RestComm as an SMPP Client and Server over SMPP by I.P over a VPN with our SMPP provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the GUI link as below:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/smpp-management/

In the previous versions of Restcomm SMSC GW the smpp and smsc settings were all avialable under one link i.e: http://127.0.0.1:8080/smsc-management/

In newer versions the developers have separated the ESME and SMPP_Management under /smpp-management

Comment: Ok thanks. Unfortunately, we chose to go with Kannel for now... So maybe in the future we try.